# How can I align images in an overflow:hidden div

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have this `div`:

```
<div style="width:10px;height:10px"></div>
```

Inside this `div` I need to put some images that have the same width as the `div` but have a different height. I don't know how many images there will be as they are dynamically generated.

If I put 2 images of `height:7px` it will show 2 images one after the other like this:
The first one appears completely and the second one is cut off just under half way.

http://conta.md/rafturi/schita.png

I want that the last image to appear completely and the other image above to be truncated, if there is not enough space in the `div`.

**Full Code**

```
<div style="float:left;width:<?=$raft[$j]['latime_produs'];?>px;height:<?=$inaltime_p‌roduse;?>px;">
    <?php for ($o=0;$o<$cate_peste;$o++) { ?>
        <img src="../xyza/<?=$raft[$j]['poza_produs'];?>" width="<?=$raft[$j]['latime_produs'];?>" height="<?=$inaltime_produs;?>" />
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what about `background-position: bottom;`?

Comment: i think not because in that example is just one image of one product. it shows dinamically. i don't kave that kind of background. here is other example : http://conta.md/rafturi/schita2.png ; in the first 2 div i have 2 products but in the third one i have 2 same products one over other - align top ; need bottom

Comment: Can you post your complete code? the `<div>` with the `<img>`s inside.

Comment: if i could set how may times to repeat background it could work

Comment: <div style="float:left;width:<?=$raft[$j]['latime_produs'];?>px;height:<?=$inaltime_produse;?>px;">
  
  <?php for ($o=0;$o<$cate_peste;$o++)
  { ?>
  <img src="../xyza/<?=$raft[$j]['poza_produs'];?>" width="<?=$raft[$j]['latime_produs'];?>" height="<?=$inaltime_produs;?>" /> 
<?php
  }
  ?>
  </div>

Comment: $cate_peste give me the number of how many products are one over each other in div

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to set the wrapper `<div>` to `position:relative;`

Then you need to have an inner wrapper `<div>` which you would set to `position:absolute;` and `bottom:0;`.

Combining this will cause the contents of the outer div to sit on the bottom of it, and any overflowing will roll off the top instead, which I think is what you're after.

I've done a [quick demo for you using JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2nj4/). The demo uses text as the content, but it would work equally well with images inside the inner div.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width` & `min-height` instead of using `width` & `height`

```
<div style="min-width:10px;min-height:10px"></div>
```

Comment: How would this solve his problem? The `div` would just expand, which is not what he asked for.

Comment: that one put my 2 one over each other products side by side. i need then one over each but align bootom not top. to start showing compleat product picture from bottom not from top.